# How to use html syntax saved in backend in the frontend with react

Tags: html, reactjs

Currently I am working in a project in which Admin is saving the html code as a whole as a string which will later be used in the front end. It is saved so that user can put their own custom css like placing of whole div, size etc. It was working for some time, but now they want the saving part as it is, but when viewing it should look little differently. Like placement of images(it's just a part of whole div), grid system.

Following is a part of html admin saves:

```
<img src="http://localhost:3001/api/v1/images/image_454812039.jpeg" style="float:none;height:170.17142857142858px;width:301px;" /><p><span style="color:rgb(0,0,0);background-color:rgb(237,237,237);">Other names of Marshall Bruce Matters</span></p>
```

as you can see, that's what I get from backend. Now in the front when user is viewing, the span should be at the top, and image should be at bottom of it in a grid.

Answer (score 1):

First of all to answer your question I will propose you to go and look at this loader `react-jsx-parser` -> https://github.com/TroyAlford/react-jsx-parser

But I would like to warn you that this method is not really recommended. It is better to have the structure in the code. Then call the source to the backend and then integrate it into your DOM.

This will make your frontend and backend easier to understand and therefore maintain

Comment: I don't think react-jsx-parser will solve the issue with putting on the element that is later in the string. As mentioned, I am trying to get <p><span> tag first and then <img> tag later. I don't think react-jsx-parser or html-parser or santize-html can do those.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem there is that the styles are not like jsx styles. They should be like:

```
style={{float:'none', height: '170.17142857142858px', width:'301px'}}
```

or

```
style={{float:'none', height: 170.17142857142858, width:301}}
```

But there is a npm package which helps getting the job done.   [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)

Hope it helps!